# tf 1.13 clip_by_global_norm can not used in mixed precision float?

Tags: tensorflow

When using tf 1.13 clip_by_global_norm function, it raised an error:

```
Tensors in list passed to 'values' of 'Pack' Op have types that don't all match.
```

If I cast all grads into the same dtypes, it brings up problems like can not add float16 with float32 in other operations.

How can I use clip_by_global_norm when the variables are in different precision: float32 and float16